# Convert strings to float in all pandas columns, where this is possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I created a pandas dataframe from a list of lists

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = [["a", "1", "2"], ["b", "3", np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = list("ABC"))
>>>   A  B    C
   0  a  1    2
   1  b  3  NaN
```

Is there a way to convert all columns of the dataframe to float, that can be converted, i.e. B and C? The following works, if you know, which columns to convert:

```
  df[["B", "C"]] = df[["B", "C"]].astype("float")
```

But what do you do, if you don't know in advance, which columns contain the numbers? When I tried

```
  df = df.astype("float", errors = "ignore")
```

all columns are still strings/objects. Similarly,

```
df[["B", "C"]] = df[["B", "C"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

converts both columns (though "B" is `int` and "C" is "float", because of the `NaN` value being present), but

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

obviously throws an error message and I don't see a way to suppress this.
Is there a possibility to perform this string-float conversion without looping through each column, to try `.astype("float", errors = "ignore")`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need parameter `errors='ignore'` in [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B      int64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

It working nice if not mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
df_list = [["a", "t", "2"], ["b", "3", np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = list("ABC"))

df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  a  t  2.0 <=added t to column B for mixed values
1  b  3  NaN

print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B     object
C    float64
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

You can downcast also `int` to `float`s:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='float')
print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float32
C    float32
dtype: object
```

It is same as:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore', downcast='float'))
print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float32
C    float32
dtype: object
```

Comment: Oh my, `apply()` has also the `errors = ignore` parameter? Is there a way to enforce `float`? `pd.to_numeric` downcasts data to the smallest numerical dtype possible, which changes for `int` columns, when `NaN` is present.

Comment: No, it is only syntactic sugar `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))`