# to_numeric() returns float values when errors = 'coerce', even if downcast = 'integer' when the list contains 'nan' values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['...', 1]
pd.to_numeric(a, errors = 'coerce', downcast = 'integer')
```

I expected the output to be,

```
array([nan,1], dtype = int8)
```

Instead, I got

```
array([nan,1.], dtype = float32)
```

What should I do to get a list of integers? 
Why does it return float values?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530210/pandas-to-numeric-downcast-signed-returning-float64 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
type(np.nan) #return float
```

it is considered as float so the problem in nan value

Comment: Thank You! How could I resolve the issue? As I need Integer values.

Comment: is (...) value  mandatory in your array?
your array must be array of numbers

Comment: I am actually using this method on a data source which contains such non-numerical values.

Comment: you can replace all (...) value with 0 before calling to_numeric so that to_numeric cast it as int8

Comment: Could you please provide some detail on how to resolve this? This right now is not very helpful as an answer.

Comment: ``` python

import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['...','1'])
mask = [not(i.isnumeric()) for i in arr]
arr[mask] = '0'
print(arr)
```